# How to ask people to re-answer a question in light of new information, when you're not sure if the answer has changed?

Tags: discussion, answers

There were a lot of questions answered before the DMG came out that hypothesized about what it might include.  Now that the DMG is out, those answers might be wrong.  If it's obvious that they are, then one could just propose a new answer with the new information.  But what if you don't know if the answers are now wrong, but want people to take another look at the question in light of all the information we now have in the DMG?

(The example I am thinking of right now is [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50054/does-casting-a-spell-from-an-item-count-as-casting-a-spell), but I have actually wanted to get updated answers on other questions in the past as well.)

The very related meta question, [What's the proper way to ask for new answers?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2960/whats-the-proper-way-to-ask-for-new-answers), suggests placing a bounty on the original question.

However, if the new information in the DMG allows me to add more detail to the question as well, would it be proper to ask a new more detailed question, referencing the first?  (I would obviously try to make it not be a duplicate, but that could be iffy.)

(If it makes a difference, the question in question is "protected".)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this is about the situation where you are not sure if the answers are any different?

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes.

Comment: Very related, and possibly duplicate: [Now that the 5e DMG is released, what is the best approach to revisit existing questions?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/now-that-the-5e-dmg-is-released-what-is-the-best-approach-to-revisit-existing-q)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Definitely related and good reference material, but this is a niche situation that is definitely worth providing advice for on its own.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't think that's quite a duplicate, though very helpful, since it's more about what to do if you *have* a new, improved answer, or want to offer improvements to the existing ones, and not if you want to ask, "hey, does anyone have a new improved answer to this?"

Comment: Reviewing my proposal there may be relevant. :)

Comment: I like your suggestion @SevenSidedDie but it definitely conflicts with another highly voted answer that says "do not duplicate" :)  Anyhow, I'm done for the night, I'll see if anything shakes out before the next time I get on here.

Answer (score 5):

Improve questions where possible. Place bounties or improve answers. Do not post duplicate questions for the sake of duplicating a question.

We have already offered this advice here: [Now that the 5e DMG is released, what is the best approach to revisit existing questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/now-that-the-5e-dmg-is-released-what-is-the-best-approach-to-revisit-existing-q) and the advice stands. If a question can be improved, improve it. It doesn't matter how old. If an answer can be improved, improve it. If you want other people to do this work, place a bounty.

Comment: When you say "improve questions" do you mean to just edit the question?  Will that be noticeable? (Will the old question rise back to the top because it has been edited?)

Comment: @PurpleVermont Yes, a change to any post on a Q&A bumps the question to the top of the front page.

Comment: I'm a little reluctant to edit a question if it changes what it is asking, from what the OP asked, to what I think one *should* ask about the issue, in light of the new information provided in the DMG.  Is it ok to edit the question if it changes the question somewhat?

Comment: That sounds like a frame challenge, and therefore a decent answer.

Comment: The OP is active on the site, so I just asked in a comment if he minds me editing it.  Seemed the polite thing to do :)

Comment: sadly, neither editing the question nor putting up a bounty has generated any contributions yet :-/  Guess no one has any thoughts on the question.  Either that or the fact that there is already an accepted answer (from before the edit/bounty) makes people less likely to visit?