# Should an answer be rewritten completely if new external info becomes available?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

My question was prompted by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198985/64093) where the rules were unclear at the time of answering. The complete **answer** was now replaced with recent info from errata. The question wasn't ever changed in a way that changes what is asked.

There is guidance on updating old answers [*e.g.* here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/how-to-ask-people-to-re-answer-a-question-in-light-of-new-information-when-you) and [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/when-rules-change-but-votes-dont-how-to-handle-it).

The guidance seems to be that answers should be improved and wrong information should be removed.

In the present case I would however say that the info is not really wrong.

**What is the right course of action in this case?**

- Complete rewrite (as was done)?
- Create a new separate answer?
- Add the new info but retain some or most of the original answer?
- something else?

Comment: Thoughtful answers to this meta should consider that the SOP is probably different when editing your own obsolete answer vs. editing someone else’s.

Comment: FWIW, my (perchance flawed) rationale in just edit-replacing instead of writing a new answer was partially influenced by the fact that my original answer mentioned that the item was already marked for errata - so it felt more like an "update" than a new answer. And that seemed a lot more convenient than making a new answer and deleting my old, while better preserving the history. Of course, editing an accepted answer to be different is... risky. The errata was unambiguous enough here that I wasn't worried about that either. Also @Anagkai thanks for making a meta question on this! :)

Answer (score 8):

What I have done in the past is to update the top of the answer with the updated information, and then left the rest as “but before this change, this is how things worked,” for historical curiosity and/or for the sake of those who upvoted the answer on the basis of that description.

As an example, [my answer to “When using a reach weapon, which squares around me can I attack?” in Pathfinder 1e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/29545/4563).

Another approach is to edit the question itself to limit it to a particular timeframe, and possibly create a new question and link to it for the updated version. This is fairly clear and clean, but it would need to be a situation in which the before and after both warranted their own question—which is pretty unusual.

The last approach—which isn’t always an option, e.g. if your answer has been accepted—is to simply delete your answer. I don’t think there’s a lot of need for this, even when you can, though.